How to convert PDF to thumbnail using Imagick in Laravel?
I am working in a phase where i need to generate all pdf's document first page as a thumbnail and upload resource to s3. I have tried to achieve this using Imagick. But I keep on getting this error:

vagrant.ERROR: Can not determine resource type of file [/tmp/TT_temp_BX476L] with MIME type [application/pdf].

The code I have tried is
 public function makePdfCoverThumbnail(int $width, int $height, TempFile $sourceFile, TempFile $destinationFile): void
    {
        $imagick = new \Imagick();
        $pdfFileName = $sourceFile->getFilename();
        \Log::info($pdfFileName);
        $imagick->setResolution(200, 200);
        $imagick->readImage("pdf:{$pdfFileName}[0]");
        $imagick->setImageBackgroundColor('white');
        $imagick->setImageAlphaChannel(\Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_REMOVE);
        $imagick->mergeImageLayers(\Imagick::LAYERMETHOD_FLATTEN);
        $imagick->thumbnailImage($width, $height, true);
        $imagick->writeImage($destinationFile->getFilename());
    }


What can I try next?

This resource seems to suggest that you don't need the pdf: prefix in the filename. (However this resource is rather old).

If this does not work, consider usingconvert on the console instead.
